# Python : Passing form-data directly in fast-api with UI

Tags: python, multipartform-data

- I am calling a API of `OmniDocs`, I am able to `Add Document` using Postman, passing it as form-data.
- When I am trying to do the same in `python` it is returning `Bad request`.
- NGOAddDocumentBDO Value

```
<NGOAddDocumentBDO>
    <cabinetName>samplecabinet</cabinetName>
    <folderIndex>3185</folderIndex>
    <documentName>Restweb postman</documentName>
    <userDBId></userDBId>
    <volumeId>1</volumeId>
    <accessType>S</accessType>
    <createdByAppName>txt</createdByAppName>
    <enableLog>Y</enableLog>
    <versionFlag>N</versionFlag>
    <textAlsoFlag></textAlsoFlag>
    <ownerType>U</ownerType>
    <ownerIndex>2</ownerIndex>
    <nameLength></nameLength>
    <thumbNailFlag>N</thumbNailFlag>
    <imageData></imageData>
    <encrFlag>N</encrFlag>
    <passAlgoType>MD5</passAlgoType>
    <userName>test123</userName>
    <userPassword>Test@1234</userPassword>
    <comment></comment>
    <locale>en_US</locale>
    <NGOAddDocDataDefCriterionBDO>
        <dataDefIndex>22</dataDefIndex>
        <dataDefName>DIGI2</dataDefName>
        <NGOAddDocDataDefCriteriaDataBDO>
            <indexId>43</indexId>
            <indexType>I</indexType>
            <indexValue>123</indexValue>
        </NGOAddDocDataDefCriteriaDataBDO>
    </NGOAddDocDataDefCriterionBDO>
    <NGOAddDocKeywordsCriterionBDO>
        <keyword></keyword>
    </NGOAddDocKeywordsCriterionBDO>
</NGOAddDocumentBDO>
```

[image]

- Postman output

[image]

- Using fastapi in python, I am passing `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`, but not able to determine where the request is going wrong, if it is working fine with postman, not able to figure out the problem in fast-api.

```
    lstr_add_document_response = "Empty"
            lxml_add_document = """
            <NGOAddDocumentBDO>
            <cabinetName>samplecabinet</cabinetName>
            <folderIndex>3185</folderIndex>
            <documentName>Restweb postman</documentName>
            <userDBId></userDBId>
            <volumeId>1</volumeId>
            <accessType>S</accessType>
            <createdByAppName>txt</createdByAppName>
            <enableLog>Y</enableLog>
            <versionFlag>N</versionFlag>
            <textAlsoFlag></textAlsoFlag>
            <ownerType>U</ownerType>
            <ownerIndex>2</ownerIndex>
            <nameLength></nameLength>
            <thumbNailFlag>N</thumbNailFlag>
            <imageData></imageData>
            <encrFlag>N</encrFlag>
            <passAlgoType>MD5</passAlgoType>
            <userName>test123</userName>
            <userPassword>Test@1234</userPassword>
            <comment></comment>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <NGOAddDocDataDefCriterionBDO>
            <dataDefIndex>22</dataDefIndex>
            <dataDefName>DIGI2</dataDefName>
            <NGOAddDocDataDefCriteriaDataBDO>
            <indexId>43</indexId>
            <indexType>I</indexType>
            <indexValue>123</indexValue>
            </NGOAddDocDataDefCriteriaDataBDO>
            </NGOAddDocDataDefCriterionBDO>
            <NGOAddDocKeywordsCriterionBDO>
            <keyword></keyword>
            </NGOAddDocKeywordsCriterionBDO>
            </NGOAddDocumentBDO>
            """
            lstr_headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            lstr_data = {'NGOAddDocumentBDO': lxml_add_document, 'file': open('/home/donny/Desktop/omnidocs/output-document/8VQUI_something.pdf', "wb+")}
            try:
                lstr_add_document_response = requests.post(gstr_omnidocs_add_document_service,
                                                           data=lstr_data,
                                                           headers=lstr_headers)
                print(gstr_omnidocs_add_document_service)
                print(lstr_data)
                print(lstr_headers)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(str(e), exc_info=True)
            print("Response text=", lstr_add_document_response.text.encode('utf8'))
            print(lstr_add_document_response.content)
    
            # replace &lt; with <
            new_lstr_add_document_response = (lstr_add_document_response.text).replace("&lt;", "<")
    
            # get the response from the add document response
            lstr_soup_response = BeautifulSoup(new_lstr_add_document_response, features="xml")
            return lstr_soup_response
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(str(e), exc_info=True)
```

Comment: Postman has function to generate code in Python (and in other languages)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe don't add header `content-type` because `requests` should add correct header.

Comment: @furas that is the only error that I am getting, the other two suggestion I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Postman` on right side should have icon `</>` to open function `Code snippet` which can generate code for different languages - even for `Python` (`requests` and `http.client`)

[image]

It gives me code which sends file in `files=...`

```
import requests

url = "http://10.10.2.41:8003/OmniBook"

payload={'NGOAddDocumentBDO': '<XML>'}
files=[
  ('file',('file',open('/path/to/file','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

But I couldn't test it.